# Dúvida sobre modularização em Aplicação MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modularização

Amigos,

Procuro sempre focar nas boas praticas de programação, e uma pratica que mais me confunde é a **Modularização**. Por exemplo, tenho o método abaixo que recebe dados de uma API e manda pra View essa coleção. Pois bem: nesse método são exercidas algumas funções diferentes, e a necessidade de modularizar é clara. Entretando, me confundo em saber como cada parte deverá ser modularizada:

```
//String da API que eu conecto.
string baseUrl = "http://endereco.com.br/api/";

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        List<employee> employee = new List<employee>();

        //Cria um HTTPClient e atribui determinados parâmetros para a conexão
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("employee");
            if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Se tudo der certo, ele vai atribuir o resulto à "response" e desserializar para JSON.
                var response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<employee>>(response);
            }
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
```

Pensei, por exemplo, em criar um método especifico para a criação e atribuição do HttpClient. Porém ele não poderia ficar nesse controller, uma vez que ele está sendo usado para acesso às páginas.

Pela experiência dos amigos, como deveremos dividir o código desse método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nas boas praticas o melhor seria que essa parte fique dentro de uma service, e ela moldada de forma generica.

```
public async Task<List<T>> ListaAsync(){
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(typeof(T).Name);
            if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Se tudo der certo, ele vai atribuir o resulto à "response" e desserializar para JSON.
                var response = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(response);
            } else {
           return T = new List<T>();
           }
        }
}
```

Nao sei como vc colocou isso baseUrl, mas nas boas praticas o melhor seria dentro do `Web.config`, porque caso voce precise mudar a url voce pode fazer diretamento no site de hospedagem.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="baseUrl" value="http://endereco.com.br/api/"/>
  </appSettings>
```

C#

```
string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseUrl"]
```

Comment: Perfeito, amigo! É exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Só uma modificação, minha assinatura ficou: "public async Task<T> Get<T>(string endpoint)", assim posso usar esse método para qualquer Get que eu for fazer. Obrigado!

Comment: Uma dica extra, se o projeto for de grande escala, implemente a arquitetura em camadas.